# Java Programming - String class and using methods

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment for a Intro. to Java programming class which I think I have almost completed, but I seem to be doing something wrong. I've tried several approaches to fix my code but everything has failed. I'm new to the methods in the String class. My assignment is to create an English translator with specific requirements which I have commented in my code below and to use the String split() method. I tried outputting the test case for the assignment but it is not calling the methods I created.

For example, "The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plain" is suppose to output: "The ain-reh in-eh Spain stays ainly-meh on-eh the plain".

I would really appreciate the feedback/advice on how I can fix my code. Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userInput;


    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

    String[] words = userInput.split("\\s+");

    for (String w : words) {

        System.out.print(wordConvert(w) + " ");
    }

}

static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    if (c.substring(0, 0).equals('a') || c.substring(0, 0).equals('e') || c.substring(0, 0).equals('i') || c.substring(0, 0).equals('o') || c.substring(0, 0).equals('u'))
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}

public static String wordConvert(String word) {

    String wordOutput = word;
    String whatIsPassed = word.substring(0,0);
    if (isVowel(word.substring(0, 0))) {
        // vowel
        wordOutput = word + "-eh";
        return wordOutput;
    } else {
        // all consonants
        if (!isVowel(word.substring(1, 1)) || (!isVowel(word.substring(1, 1)) && !isVowel(word.substring(2, 2)))) {

            // escape with no changes
            return wordOutput;
        }

        else {
            // single consonant
            wordOutput = word.substring(1) + "-" + word.substring(0, 0) + "eh";
            return wordOutput;

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `isVowel` function, you want

```
c.charAt(0) == ('a')
```

or a substring of length 1. Right now you are comparing an empty string to a list of vowels, which will always return false. This is similar to every other time you use substring, where `substring(x,x)` will always be empty.

It's just much more straightforward to use the `charAt` method instead since you are doing character v character comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (c.substring(0, 0).equals('a')...
```

Is wrong, `char` is a *primitive* type, and not an object, though it can't have methods. `char` checks equal using `==`. Then again, `char` is a single character; no substring possible.

There are some built-in convenience methods defined in Java packed in the `Character` class.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. The code started getting confusing for me as I started switching things around and getting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You were not too far... After fixing the trivial compiler errors, and rewriting `isVowel` to take a `char` and simplify its logic, this seems to work fine:

```
static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static String wordConvert(String word) {
    String wordOutput = word;
    if (isVowel(word.charAt(0))) {
        // vowel
        wordOutput = word + "-eh";
        return wordOutput;
    } else {
        // all consonants
        if (!isVowel(word.charAt(1)) || !isVowel(word.charAt(2))) {
            // escape with no changes
            return wordOutput;
        } else {
            // single consonant
            wordOutput = word.substring(1) + "-" + word.charAt(0) + "eh";
            return wordOutput;
        }
    }
}
```

`wordConvert` can be further simplified to:

```
public static String wordConvert(String word) {
    if (isVowel(word.charAt(0))) {
        return word + "-eh";
    }
    if (!isVowel(word.charAt(1)) || !isVowel(word.charAt(2))) {
        return word;
    }
    return word.substring(1) + "-" + word.charAt(0) + "eh";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I started messing things around and it started getting confusing for me. You made it easier to understand. I'm going to need more practice and study the methods more in the String class. Thanks again.